# Using hashmap of POJO in drools drl

Tags: java, hashmap, drools

I am very new to Drools and using it for a quick prototype.
I have a Pojo class that has two hashmaps.

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    private Map<String, Integer> currMap= new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Integer> historyMap = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I want to write rules in Drools to check value of keys in both the hashmaps. An example is below

```
rule "test1"
when
$mc : MyTestClass(currMap["Name 1"] == 1, historyMap["Name 1"] == null)

then
System.out.println("Condition for Name 1 matched");
end

rule "test2"
when
$mc : MyTestClass(currMap["Name 2"] == 1, historyMap["Name 2"] == null)

then
System.out.println("Condition for Name 2 matched");
end

rule "test3"
when
$mc : MyTestClass(currMap["Name 3"] == 1, historyMap["Name 3"] == null)

then
System.out.println("Condition for Name 3 matched");
end
```

However, when I run this, I only get the output from test3 even if test1 and test2 rules match. I even changed test3 rule to look for a non-existing key (replaced "Name 3" with some junk characters) and still get output only for the last rule - test3. It seems like something syntactically wrong with my drl file in using HashMap.

Could anyone help me with using HashMap's value inside drl file write rules?

Thanks,

Comment: Please add the code for creating and inserting the facts.

Comment: There is a missing double quote in all your `System.out.println`. Is that a an error in your post? Or does your DRL look like this?

Comment: Double quote was a typo. Corrected that. thanks